# How to write compressjs output to a file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write the output of a [compressjs](https://github.com/cscott/compressjs) compressFile function to a file.

Right now I just have the default code that he supplies on the page. I am newer to node and I guess I really don't know where to start. Basically I want to take 'compressed' and write it to 'file.bz2'

```
var compressjs = require('compressjs');
var algorithm = compressjs.Bzip2;
var data = new Buffer('Example data', 'utf8');
var compressed = algorithm.compressFile(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `compressFile` function can take a "stream"-like object as second parameter, but it is not working with a [`fs.createWriteStream`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) object (because it does not implement the required `writeByte` function).

You could take a look at how the executable of the package creates the output file:

- [creating the output "stream" object](https://github.com/cscott/compressjs/blob/master/bin/compressjs#L106)
- [starting compression and flushing the file](https://github.com/cscott/compressjs/blob/master/bin/compressjs#L175)